# Bootstrap-How to make the bootstrap input dropdown buttons selectable-Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap dropdown buttons for selectable dropdown with search input field: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns. 
however in the example listed in the bootstrap components, I'm unable to select the dropdown option.

Ex: [image]

how can i make the button dropdown selectable so as to be able to select any option from within.
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are trying to accomplish this
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
there have a lot of options that you can use, like select more that 1 in a dropdown

Comment: well, the above example provides multiselect of dropdown options.I was looking for more like  a simple dropdown styled with bootstrap css.